# Subtração entre dois campos de mesmo valor não dá zero- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Alguém saberia me explicar: 
Fiz um join entre duas tabelas. Ambas trazem o mesmo valor em seus campos. E quando subtraio um valor menos o outro, não dá zero. Como isso é possível?

```
E1_SALDO  = 990,42

BAIXZ0    = 990,42

SUBTRACAO = 990,42 - 990,42 = 1,13686837721616E-13
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo desse campo?

Comment: Ambos são numéricos.

Comment: Catharina, provavelmente alguma coluna está declarada como ponto flutuante (_real_ ou _float_). Ou ambas.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por que o padrão decimal do SQL Server usa '.' no lugar da ','

Para corrigir o seu calculo basta usar a função REPLACE.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Isso deve resolver o seu problema:

```
declare @E1_SALDO   decimal = REPLACE('990,42', ',', '.'),
        @BAIXZ0     decimal = REPLACE('990,42', ',', '.')

select @E1_SALDO - @BAIXZ0
```

Comment: Acho que não entendi sua explicação. No exemplo coloquei 990,42. Mas o cálculo é feito com valores que estão no banco. A subtração entre valores ocorre para todos títulos e pela primeira vez, a subtração de dois valores iguais não foi zero. Eu não deveria ter que fazer esta conversão para todo cálculo que eu fizer no banco. Nunca o fiz.